# UWP: Write file in a generic location using StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList

Tags: c#, uwp, file-permissions

I have the following scenario in my UWP App:

1. The user imports a file (e.g. using a `FilePicker`, or by dragging a file onto the app, etc.) into my application.
2. We save some metadata of this file inside our internal database, and we also save a token retrieved using the following code:

   ```
   string token = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);
   ```
3. The user closes the app.
4. The user re-opens the app.
5. Now we want to overwrite the initial file. To do this, we retrieve the StorageFile using this code:

   ```
   StorageFile exportTarget = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(token);
   ```

but when I try to write into the file, e.g. using

```
using (IRandomAccessStream fs = await exportTarget.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
```

I get an exception complaining that `exportTarget` is **ReadOnly**.

How can I have access to such file in **Write** mode?

Comment: When I followed the above steps and tried to open the random-access stream with ReadWrite, it worked well, I didn't receive the same exception. May I know how you save the metadata of the file and where is the file you selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was not a strict problem of the `StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList`.

The problem happens in fact only if the user imports a file by dragging-and-dropping the file into the app: in this case, the `DataPackageView.GetStorageItemsAsync()` method returns a list of `StorageFile` that are ReadOnly.

So, the only way to overwrite those files is by using `PathIO` methods, as described in this post: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2421